# Need to find P(Y < 2) by conditioning on X where Y is uniformly distributed over (0,x)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

The density of $X$ is $f(x) = xe^{-x}$, for $x > 0$. Given $X = x$, $Y$ is
uniformly distributed on $(0, x)$.

I need to find $P(Y < 2)$ by conditioning on $X$.

Please explain step by step... I am new to conditional distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density is the product of the density of $X$ with the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$.
$$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(x,y) &= f_X(x) \cdot f_{Y \mid X=x}(y) \\[1ex]&= x\mathrm e^{-x} \mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x) \cdot \frac{1}{x} \mathbf{1}_{(0, x)}(y)\\[1ex]&=\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)\,\mathbf 1_{(0,x)}(y)\end{align}$$

Then, integrate this joint density over the region of the $(x,y)$ plane specified by $y < 2$.
$$\begin{align}
P(Y < 2)
&= \iint_{y < 2} f_{X,Y}(x, y) \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy
\\[1ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^2 f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx
\\[1ex]
&= \int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-x} \int_0^{\min\{2, x\}} \,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx
\\[1ex]
&~~\vdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you for the edits/corrections

Comment: xe^−x1[0,∞)(x) ⋅ 1/x 1(0,x)(y), can you please explain this, how'd you drive this? I am new to this, i didnt understand what is [0,∞)

Comment: @GamesBroken The notation $\mathbf{1}_{(0, \infty)}(x)$ is a function that equals $1$ if $x > 0$, and equals $0$ otherwise. It is a way to encode "the density of $X$ is zero everywhere except when $x > 0$. The second part of the joint density is the density of the uniform distribution on the interval $(0, x)$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. 
Here ∬fX,Y(x,y)dxdy why do we need to integrate over dx and dy... can we just integrate joint function with dx to get P(y) and then plug in values y<2?

Comment: @GamesBroken  Yes, that is how it works. $$\begin{align}\int_0^2 \color{blue}{f_Y(y)}\,\mathrm d y~&=~\int_0^2\color{blue}{\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d y\\&=~\int_0^2\color{blue}{\int_y^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm d x}\,\mathrm d y\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @angryavian and GrahamKemp